# Find corresponding values in two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to find corresponding values in the two Pandas DataFrame.

Input:
df1:

```
   server    system     directions msgTYPE    msgID      count
0     1       sys1_in       in      ADT       MSG0001      1
1     1       sys1_in       in      ADT       MSG0002      1
2     1       sys1_in       in      ADT       MSG0003      1
3     1       sys1_in       in      ADT       MSG0004      1
```

df2:

```
   server    system     directions  msgTYPE     msgID      count
0     1       sys2_out       out      ADT       MSG0001      1
1     1       sys2_out       out      ADT       MSG0001      1
2     1       sys3_out       out      ADT       MSG0003      1
3     1       sys4_out       out      ADT       MSG0004      1
```

Output schould be:

```
     system_in       system_out        count
0     sys1_in         sys2_out           2
1     sys1_in         sys3_out           1
2     sys1_in         sys4_out           1
```

So I have to build from the two DF one df with the columns with in and out systems, there are with the mesgID correlated.

I am making it with the df.itertuples and df.goupby in the way:

```
model = pd.DataFrame(columns=['in', 'out', 'count'])
for item in ins.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
        selected = outs.query('msgID == "%s"' % (getattr(item, "msgID")))
        for row in selected.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas2'):
            model = model.append({'in': getattr(item, "system"), 'out': getattr(row, "system"), 'count': 1},
                                 ignore_index=True)
result = model.groupby(['in', 'out'])['count'].sum().reset_index()
```

It works, but it is extream inefficient, the input Frames(df1, df2) have about 2 millions rows. Some one know more efficient way which is build in the Pandas framework?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by first `merging` the dataframes by the corresponding columns and then using `GroupBy` with [`named_aggregations`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling) (new in `pandas >= 0.25.0`):

```
columns = [col for col in df1.columns if col != 'system']

mrg = df1.merge(df2, on=columns, suffixes=['_in', '_out'])

mrg.groupby(columns).agg(
    system_in=('system_in', 'first'),
    system_out=('system_out', 'first'),
    count=('system_in', 'size')
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Output**

```
  system_in system_out  count
0   sys1_in   sys2_out      2
1   sys1_in   sys3_out      1
2   sys1_in   sys4_out      1
```

---

If you want to keep the columns as information, just use `merge` and `GroupBy.count`:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=columns, suffixes=['_in', '_out'])\
   .groupby(columns, as_index=False).count()
```

**Output**

```
   server directions msgTYPE    msgID  count  system_in  system_out
0       1         in     ADT  MSG0001      1          2           2
1       1         in     ADT  MSG0003      1          1           1
2       1         in     ADT  MSG0004      1          1           1
```

Comment: Hi, thank You for Your proposition. It looks very good, but I can't merge DFs properly. I allways get empty DF. No matter if i am doing it with conditions(, on=columns, suffixes=['_in', '_out']) or without. Any tips?

Comment: Hi Erfan, could You answer? I still can't merge two DFs.